# PendingIntent clears entry on App killed from Recents in Motorola Device

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, motorola

AlarmManager is set based on PandingIntent's entry so that multiple alarms does not get set.

```html
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(appContext, ALARM_REQUEST_ID, intent, 0);

boolean isAlarmSet = (PendingIntent.getService(appContext, ALARM_REQUEST_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
```

This runs fine in all devices except Moto G3.
All the devices return proper value so that Alarm reset does not happen & works very fine, but in Moto G3 device, once app is closed, it resets PendingIntent entry and again alarm gets set.

In short, every time alarm gets set even though it's already set.

Issue is with app close & pendingIntent entry reset happening with mentioned device.

Can anyone help in this?

Comment: How do you know it is already set?

Comment: PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(appContext, ALARM_REQUEST_ID, intent, 0);

boolean isAlarmSet = (PendingIntent.getService(appContext, ALARM_REQUEST_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
 
This code helps to identify alarm is set or not

Comment: And how do you know, on the MOTO G3, if the alarm is set? Maybe, on that device, the alarm is no longer set. That's why I'm asking "how do you know?" I'm not asking what code you use to determine if the alarm is set. I'm asking how do you (as a person) absolutely know that the alarm is set even if the call to `PendingIntent.getService()` returns `null`.